# What is it exactly?

Tags: hadoop, nosql

Why in this link:{http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-cloud_apache/#figure2} in figure1,apache hadoop is defined as a Platform as a service but in http://nosql-databases.org it is defined as a no sql wide column store database?

I mean when working with hadoop do I need a database too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second link is a 404, and no Hadoop itself is no database.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is a basically a collection of java software that fundamentally provides two things:

1. A distributed file system implementation.
2. A framework for writing, and running Map Reduce jobs written in Java.

Many things are built on top of these two pieces (like HBase, which is probably the columnar datastore you have read about).

A good resource for learning more about Hadoop is the [apache project page documetation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/). If that looks confusing, there is also a book called 'Hadoop: The Definitive Guide' which is pretty good reading.

If you want to read about how it all began, I'd recommend reading [this google paper](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html) upon which Hadoop is based

Hope that helps.